# ACLs not working in Capacity Scheduler in YARN (CDH5)

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

ACLs is not wroking in Capacity Scheduler in CDH-5. Please see the below config. Only user1 and user2 should be able to queue2 and queue1 but all users are able to access all queues.

Let me know if there is a solution

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
    <value>batch,default</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queues</name>
    <value>queue1,queue2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.capacity</name>
    <value>80</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name>
    <value>20</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queue1.capacity</name>
    <value>70</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queue2.capacity</name>
    <value>30</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queue1.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>user1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queue2.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>user2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queue1.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.queue2.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>20000</value>
  </property> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As states CHD5 documentation, Capacity Scheduler is not supported.

[Reference](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_mapreduce_to_yarn_migrate.html#concept_nqs_pmy_xl_unique_3)